# Some notation from a paper by H. Toda

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm trying to read Toda's paper "Complex of the standard paths and n-ad homotopy groups" and I'm running into trouble with a definition---here's the text (slightly rephrased)

> Let $K$ be a CW-complex and let  $K_1 , \ldots, K_n$ be subcomplexes
>   such that $K_1\cap \cdots \cap K_n$ is nonempty, and let $e_0$ be a
>   vertex in this intersection.  Denote by $I(n)$ the set of indices 
>   $\{1,\ldots ,n\}$. For each subset $J\subseteq I(n)$,  we associate the
>   subcomplex $K_J=K_{j_1}\cap \cdots \cap K_{J_r}$  where 
>   $J= \{j_1,···,j_r\}$.  Denote $\partial K_J= \bigcup_{J'\subset J, J'\neq J} K_{J'}$.

My problem is that

1. Toda does not define $K_\varnothing$, but it is reasonable to define it to be $K$ itself; in this case $\partial K_J = K$ for all $J$, clearly not what was intended.
2. If we discard $\varnothing$, then we easily see that $\partial K_J = \bigcup_{j\in J} K_j$.  Why didn't he define it that way?
3. Clearly from context, this is not what he meant! Because later he talks about the pair $(K_J , \partial K_J)$, indicating that $\partial K_J$ is a subcomplex of $K_J$.

So my question is:

> What is the intended meaning of the notation $\partial K_J$?

My guess is that he got the direction of inclusion backwards, but I'd love to have some confirmation from a knowledgeable person.

Comment: I haven't looked at it, but my guess is that there's a typo in his paper. It should likely read: $\partial K_J= \bigcup_{J'\supset J, J'\neq J} K_{J'}$, so that $K_{J'} \subset K_J$.

Comment: I agree with your interpretations. But (tangentially) I wonder if one should also assume that $K_J \neq K_{J'}$ for $J\neq J'$. Otherwise one could have $K_J=K_{J'}$ but $\partial K_J\neq \partial K_{J'}$, which makes for bad notation.